# Need to create a auto populate dropdown with typo Typo Tolerance

Tags: meteor, algolia

I'm new being to Algolia, I want to implement auto populate dropdown in my example. I have create account and i have API-Key. I want to access my local database. I do not want to upload my data to Algolia. I can i integrate in my example?

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an autocomplete dropdown menu in your application, I would recommend you to take a look at the [Autocomplete guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/auto-complete#introduction) from the Algolia documentation.

However, if you don't want to upload your data to Algolia, it won't be a good fit for you as Algolia is a SaaS company. It means that all the data has to be sent to the Algolia servers to index them and make them searchable.